# Seek bar progress when button pressed

Tags: android, seekbar, android-progressbar, buttonclick

I have made a simple android project with a single activity containing three buttons and a seek bar,Now i want is that when i press 1st button the seek bar should directly progressed 33%(without showing progress),when 2nd button pressed the seek bar should progressed again by 33% second time and when third button pressed the seek bar should full progressed..my code is as below:

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.seekabardemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn,btn1,btn2;
SeekBar sk;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
      sk=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });
      btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
      btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you....Please help me..!

Please help me ..thank you..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this three statements in click events of each button respectively.

```
sk.setProgress(sk.getMax()/3);
sk.setProgress(sk.getMax()*2/3);
sk.setProgress(sk.getMax());
```

Comment: @jignesh-Thank you brothr..its working..can i ask a simple problem?when i again run the app,the progress bar shows last progress used.so how to set progress bar at starting postion when run it..!

Comment: you welcome, you can set `sk.setProgress(0);` when you want to set at starting position.

Comment: @jignesh-tnx bro..! have a nyc day.:)

Answer (score 0):

To set a seekBar progress just :

```
sk.setProgress(ProgressToSet);
```

to get the maximum possible progress just:

```
sk.getMax();
```

to get a porcentage of a seekbar just:

```
sk.setProgress(sk.getMax()/100*YourPercentage);
```